# Google+ Location Sharing: How to share only city level locations

Tags: google-plus, location-services

For some time, Google+ contains the possibility to share your current location with your friends. This feature is similar to Google Latitude but uses a different permission-system: Where Latitude uses a seperate friend list (the Latitude Friends), Google+ uses the people from your circles to check, who can see your location.

In the settings of the location sharing (in the Google+ App, in the drawer "Locations", Settings), I can select which people can see "who can see your best available location". All these people see my exact location, so determined by GPS (if available). If a person is not included in this list, the person does not see my location at all.

**Question: How can I select which persons can only see my city, but not my exact location? Just like it was possible on latitude? As expained above, I only see the possiblity to share the exact location or to share no location at all.**

Comment: From what I can see, you can't, unless you change your location settings to be manually updated.

Comment: You still can't. However, if you check in to Google+, you can choose "city location".

Answer (score 2):

This is now addressed in [Google+ v4.1](https://plus.google.com/101870761930221849874/posts/HNSJByBhDin)

> **4. Location sharing includes more controls**
>   Starting today you can share your pinpoint or city-level location with others (if you want), and you can do so on a circle-by-circle basis. For example: you can share your pinpoint location with family, and your city-level location with co-workers. You can also use circles to filter who appears on your “Locations” map.
>
> It’s rolling out to Google Play over the next few days ([goo.gl/xaxMx](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.plus))...